# How to import entire own module in Python as an alias?

Tags: python, python-import, relative-import

I have a directory structure like the following:

```
my-package/
    config/
        __init__.py
        constants.py
        logging.py
    app.py
```

From within `config/__init__.py`, I'd like to do an import along the lines of:

```py
import .constants as const
```

or

```py
from .constants import * as const
```

But of course neither syntax is valid.

Just wanted to ask if anyone has any ideas on how to achieve this.

I looked through several other related SO posts, and none of them seem to address this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
from . import constants as const
```

which means "from the current package level (`.`), import `constants` and alias it as `const`.